# Concatenate 2 comma separated values in two columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, explode

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Col1    Col2       Col3     Col4
1,2,3   10,11,12    ABC     A1B1
4       13          DEF     TEST
5,6     14,15       XYZ     C1D1
```

My output should be like this: (where first comma separated value goes with first comma separated value in another column creating rows and giving the counts as a column)

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Count
1       10      ABC     A1B1    1
2       11      ABC     A1B1    2
3       12      ABC     A1B1    3
4       13      DEF     TEST    1
5       14      XYZ     C1D1    1
6       15      XYZ     C1D1    2
```

I have tried using the  `explode` function but it creates the rows of columns making multiple different combinations.

Edited:
The code I've tried:

```
df.Col1 = df.Col1.str.split(',')
df = df.explode('Col1').reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it created the multiple combinations of Col1 with the rest of columns.

Looking forward for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
#spliting 'Col1' and 'Col2' column values
df['Col1']=df['Col1'].str.split(',')
df['Col2']=df['Col2'].str.split(',')
df=df.agg(pd.Series.explode)
#OR
#df=df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
#Finally create a count column:
df['Count']=df.groupby(['Col3','Col4']).cumcount()+1
#If needed reset the index:
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

output of df:

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Count
0   1       10      ABC     A1B1    1
0   2       11      ABC     A1B1    2
0   3       12      ABC     A1B1    3
1   4       13      DEF     TEST    1
2   5       14      XYZ     C1D1    1
2   6       15      XYZ     C1D1    2
```